# For a Pythagorean triple $a, b, c \in N$, if a is even and a, b, c have no common factors, prove that $c-a$ and $c+a$ are perfect squares.

Tags: diophantine-equations, euclidean-geometry

What property(s) should I examine to approach this problem?

Comment: Please edit the title into the question, so the question standing alone makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  If $x$ and $y$ are integers and $xy$ is a perfect square, then $x$ and $y$ are both perfect squares. . .

. . . or are they?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on David's hint: $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ $$b^2=c^2-a^2$$ $$b^2=(c+a)(c-a)$$ Take it from there?

Comment: What needs to be done from here? How do I know that $(c+a)$ and $(c-a)$ are both squares?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Unique Factorization Theorem? You can use it to prove that if two numbers are relatively prime, and their product is a square, then each of the two numbers is a square. Of course, you still have to prove that the two numbers in question are relatively prime....

Answer (score 1):

If a is even and coprime to b then it is represented by $ 2mn $ for $ gcd(n,m) = 1 $ and n , m not both odd in Euclids Formula.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

$ c + a = m^2 + 2mn + n^2 = (m + n)^2 $

$ c - a = m^2 - 2mn + n^2 = (m - n)^2 $

Comment: True, but overkill. These formulas aren't needed.

Comment: You may be right but i like this approach because it answers each case of the OP in less than half a line and encodes all the answers in terms of m , n :)

Comment: Well, it solves the problem in less than half a line, plus however many lines it takes to prove the formulas for $a$ and $c$.